# Авторизация на удаленном сервере через php+curl

Tags: php, curl, авторизация, 1с

Есть облачный сервер с развернутой на нем 1С.
Мне необходимо удаленно с сайта подключиться к ее базе. Если я вручную ввожу в браузере путь https://terminal.scloud.ru/scxxxx_basex/ws/Exchange?wsdl у меня запрашивается авторизация логин+пароль, как на скриншоте:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я ввожу в браузере и получаю корректный ответ.

Но задача - сделать такое же через php, чтобы ответ был получен и обработан на сайте. И проблема в том, что я не понимаю, через какие переменные мне передать логин и пароль. И, в итоге, мне возвращается Ошибка HTTP 401.2 — Unauthorized

```
// создаем подключение
$ch = curl_init('https://terminal.scloud.ru/scxxxx_basex/ws/Exchange?wsdl');
// устанавлваем даные для отправки
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postData);
// флаг о том, что нужно получить результат
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
// отправляем запрос
$response = curl_exec($ch);
// закрываем соединение
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Нужно добавить curl_setopt с передачей логина пароля. Погуглите, примеров полно, если вдруг никто кусок кода тут не напишет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "логин:пароль");
//и т.к. это http аутентификация
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
```